# file_get_contents does not find file

Tags: php, json, file, path, file-get-contents

The following code tries to load the file content into a string.

```
    // Loads the forecast from json
    public function loadForecast()
    {       
        try {

            $filename = "../../forecast/forecast.json";

            echo "Dateiname: '" . $filename . "'\n";
            echo "Pfad: '" . realpath($filename) . "'\n";

            if ($forecastContent = file_get_contents($filename) !== false) {

                echo "got content";
            }
            else {

                echo "no content";
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {

            echo "Caught exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me my fault? I'm always getting "no content". realpath does print "" (empty string).

My Webspace hierachie is

- /

  - Backend

    - my PHP file
  - forecast

    - forecast.json

Comment: try absolute path for filename, sometimes it fails to work with relative paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many `../` in the path. You only need to go up 1 level to get to the common ancestor of the `Backend` directory and the file. So it should be `../forecast/forecast.json`

Comment: okay... tried this. See Edit

Comment: I reverted the edit. The question needs to contain the error, so that the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use ./ instead of ../ :-)

Comment: This is not an answer (i.e., a relevant result for a clearly-delimited problem which might be helpful to other people); just a realisation of your mistake regarding absolute/relative paths. Note that your question doesn't state the problem clearly as far as the current path is not mentioned (the whole point here: what explains why "./" works and "../" doesn't). Better edit your question by including this solution and a clear description of the problem (e.g., the script was run from directory X/Y and tried to access directory X).